# How do you use Crystal Reports 2011 with Sql Server Express 2012?

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to find out how to use crystal reports with sql server.  I know in .net there is an "engine" that you can use to run a crystal report, but what if I just want to use sql server and CR?  Is there a way to load the CR .rpt into Sql Server and it use the .net engine there?  Do I need to write a .net program to view the .rpt files?  Is that something that sql server can server if I created a Stored Procedure?

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use crystal reports viewer (It's free) to view your rpt's, as far as the sql server goes, I am not aware of a way of displaying rpt's in sql server.